# How to fetch the values from the String to store in a seprate string upto certain part

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, string, substring

Hi I need to store the certain part of the string and store it in a separate integer variable.

My Final

```
string getResult = {"httpStatus":200,"httpRequestUri":"/sfsImagingservices/documents/followup/annuity","message":"HTTP request succeeded"}
```

My req is to fetch the Httpstatus:200 in a seprate integer or variable.

req to help me out for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your String is in fact valid JSON. Therefore, you can parse it into Map and get values by key.

```
Map<String, Object> ans = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(getResult);
Integer toStore = (Integer) ans.get('httpStatus');
```

Comment: Can you please post here your actual code? At least, in the getResult String you do not have single-quotes.

Comment: You probably need to cast the result of `ans.get()` to your target type (Integer, in this case).

Comment: Sorry actually here variable should be of Object type not Integer : Its working Thanks for your help :)